# Getter seg fault

Tags: c++

i have make simple getter who return seg fault and i don't kwow where is the problem :

There is a class "game" who containt two players and one tray:

```
> #ifndef PARTIE_H
> #define PARTIE_H
> 
> #include <string>
> #include <iostream>
> 
> class partie {
>     class joueur * joueur1;
>     class joueur * joueur2;
>     class plateau * jeu;
> 
> public:
>     partie();
>     void initialize(std::string nomj1, std::string nomj2, int tailleplateau);
>     int info();
>     ~partie();
> 
> };
> 
> #endif // PARTIE_H
```

the .cpp :

```
> #include "partie.h"
> #include "joueur.h"
> #include "plateau.h"
> #include <string>
> #include <iostream>
> 
> partie::partie() {
>     plateau * jeu = new plateau(0);
>     joueur * joueur1 = new joueur("test", 1);
>     joueur * joueur2 = new joueur("test2", 2);
> 
> }
> 
> void partie::initialize(std::string nomj1, std::string nomj2, int
> tailleplateau) {
>     plateau * jeu = new plateau(tailleplateau);
>     joueur * joueur1 = new joueur(nomj1, 1);
>     joueur * joueur2 = new joueur(nomj2, 2); }
> 
> int partie::info() {   return joueur1->getIdentifiant();
> 
> }
> 
> 
> partie::~partie() {
> 
> }
```

the class player :

```
> #ifndef JOUEUR_H
> #define JOUEUR_H
> #include <string>
> #include <iostream>
> 
> class joueur {
>     std::string nom;
>     int identifiant;
> 
> public:
>     joueur();
>     joueur(std::string name, int num);
>     std::string getName();
>     int getIdentifiant(); };
> 
> #endif // JOUEUR_H
```

the .cpp

```
> #include "joueur.h"
> #include <string>
> #include <iostream>
> 
> joueur::joueur() {
>     this->nom="DEFAULT";
>     this->identifiant=0; }
> 
> joueur::joueur(std::string name, int num) {
>     this->nom=name;
>     this->identifiant=num; }
> 
> int joueur::getIdentifiant() {
>     return identifiant; }
> 
> std::string joueur::getName() {
>     return nom; }
```

anyone see an error ? thank you for help

Comment: main.cpp :
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "partie.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    //MainWindow w;
    //w.show();
    partie * newgame;
    newgame->initialize("dylan","bob",13);
    newgame->info();
    return a.exec();
}

Comment: For some reason you did things correctly in `joueur` but wrongly in `partie`.

Answer (score 1):

there is quite a few errors, indentation for example is a big one. please run your code via clang-format or astyle, it would be much easier to review.

- don't use this-> when you don't need it, this is not java.
- don't get confused with **local** variables and **class members** (this is your error)

> ```
> plateau * jeu = new plateau(tailleplateau);
> joueur * joueur1 = new joueur(nomj1, 1);
> joueur * joueur2 = new joueur(nomj2, 2); }
> ```

Here you create a **local** variable named jeu, jouer1 and jouer2, but it looks like you also declared those variables in your class, so the fix is simple:

```
 jeu = new plateau(tailleplateau);
 joueur1 = new joueur(nomj1, 1);
 joueur2 = new joueur(nomj2, 2);
```

Do not redeclare them. :)

Some more tips:
- C++ is not java, you don't need to new things usually:
- there's no need to add your joeurs / plateau on the heap, you can declare them on the stack safely (ie, no pointers)
- if you think you should really create them on the heap (pointers), don't use raw pointers, use a smart pointer (yours should look like unique_ptr)

```
class Game {
    Game() : player1(make_unique<Player>());
    }
    private:
    std::unique_ptr<Player> player1;
};
```

This should remove your memory issues. Now, if it continues to happen, please post the debug output or the backtrace.